# Event binding not working Angular2

Tags: angular, interpolation, event-binding

I want the clicked div content to appear inside another div (via interpolation). But when I click on a div - nothing appears inside my "view" div. Please, look at my code below:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
<div class="wrap">
  <div (click)="clicked($event)">
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
  </div>
  <div (click)="clicked($event)">
    <h2>Hello {{year}}</h2>
  </div>
  <div (click)="clicked($event)">
    <h2>Hello {{surname}}</h2>
  </div>
  <div (click)="clicked($event)">
    <h2>Hello {{country}}</h2>
  </div>
  <div (click)="clicked($event)">
    <h2>Hello {{cartoon}}</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="view">
  {{target}}
</div>

  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  year: string;
  surname: string;
  country: string;
  cartoon: string;


  clicked(event) {
    var target = event.target;
  }


constructor() {
this.name = 'Angular2'
 this.year = '1989'
  this.surname = 'Connor'
   this.country = 'USA'
    this.cartoon = 'Tom & Jerry'
  }



}
```

It's not working as expected. 
[Here's my Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/yWsDkYdqIStkLX7yKMFB?p=preview)

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding to the template is with `this`. You are binding the event to a local variable.
So your class should look like this:

```
export class App {
  name:string;
  year: string;
  surname: string;
  country: string;
  cartoon: string;
  element: any;
  target:any;

  clicked(event) {
    this.target = event.target.innerText;
  }
```

Updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/cnA0nGTjdsHGqCKWTQ7c?p=preview